# How do generations work, in Westerly?

Tags: killjoys

I've heard people mentioning generations,  but I've never figured out how's it's set up.

Do seventh generation get something? Free passage out of Westerly? Who were the first generation?

Answer (score 3):

In the final episode [Delle] mentions the Seventh Generation Accord:

> A long time ago the Nine Families of Qresh enacted the Seventh Generation Accord, which declared that if people worked hard and without problems, after seven generations they would be granted land on Leith. That promise is now coming due as families on have worked to gain this land grant under the accord.

~[Killjoys wiki](http://killjoys.wikia.com/wiki/Westerley)

Leith is one of the moons of Qresh, asking with Westerly

Comment: It is mentioned in several episodes, but that is probably the most concise reference.

Comment: @trisped I caught bits of it discussed,  but never followed it. Now I've seen the last episode I've looked it up